# how to use the foreign key ?is this correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

class CustomerDetail(models.Model):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True,default='')
dob = models.DateField(default='')
def __str__(self):
return self.name
```

class orderview(models.Model):

```
reference = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
customer = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
overalltotal = models.ForeignKey(CustomerDetail, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
return self.reference
```

class orderdetails(models.Model):

```
product = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
quantity = models.IntegerField()
unit_price = models.IntegerField()
total= models.CharField(max_length=30)
orderid =  models.ForeignKey(orderview,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

def get_total(self):
result = self.quantity * self.unit_price
return result

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
self.total = self.get_total()
super(orderdetails, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You can not use `SET_NULL` if the field is not NULL-able (a field is nullable if `null=True`).

Comment: can you tell with code ?